# Manipulate FXML Node from outside of Controller, AND Application class

Tags: java, fxml

I need to manipulate an element from the Controller class. However, every example I’ve managed to find does this manipulation through the class that extends Application.

I need to manipulate the TextField inputText from VBoxSampleController in the class Main.

The manipulation is as follows:

```
inputText.setText(“TEST”);
```

The desired result is once the FXML application is launched, the inputText TextField is pre-populated with the text “TEST”.

My confusion stems from how to manipulate this field anywhere but:

- VBoxSampleController
- UIManager

The act of setting VBoxsampleController static so that I can access it by using the class name:

```
UIManager.vbsc.inputText.setText("TEST");
```

Does nothing. The element in the launched FXML window does not change. It remains empty.
This project is taken from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-applications-efxclipse/ because I can’t create a new FXML application at this time.

Thanks.

FULL CODE:

```
/* Main */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.main(args);
        // Does nothing
        // UIManager.vbsc.inputText.setText("TEST");
        // I want to change inputText here
    }
}
```

```
/* UIManager */
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class UIManager extends Application {

    public static VBoxSampleController vbsc;

    public FXMLLoader loader;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("VBoxSample.fxml"));
            VBox root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            vbsc = loader.getController();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

```
/* VBoxController */
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class VBoxSampleController {
    @FXML
    // The reference of inputText will be injected by the FXML loader
    public TextField inputText;
    // The reference of outputText will be injected by the FXML loader
    @FXML
    private TextArea outputText;

    // location and resources will be automatically injected by the FXML loader
    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TabPane mainPane;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    // Add a public no-args constructor
    public VBoxSampleController() {
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void printOutput() {
        outputText.setText(inputText.getText());
    }
}
```

```
<!-- FXML -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="VBoxSampleController">
  <children>
    <Label alignment="CENTER_LEFT" cache="true" cacheHint="SCALE" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Please insert Your Input here:" textAlignment="LEFT" />
    <TextField fx:id="inputText" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printOutput" text="OK" textAlignment="CENTER" />
    <Label alignment="CENTER_LEFT" cache="true" cacheHint="SCALE" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Your Input:" textAlignment="LEFT" />
    <TextArea fx:id="outputText" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: When you change components you need to do it on the platform thread. Right now you are doing it on the main thread. Do you get an error when you use the static method?

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because you're trying to modify a static variable from a non-static method:

```
@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) { // non-static method

    vbsc = loader.getController(); // vbsc is a static variable

}
```

If I'm guessing right, you're trying to dynamically update an FXML field when the application starts. So you can simply achieve this by using controller's initialize() method:

```
public class VBoxSampleController {

    @FXML                        // I suggest you to always keep class variable 
    private TextField inputText; // field private or non-public to prevent
                                 // unauthorized modifications

    ...

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        String text = "TEST"; // or any other at-runtime generated string
        inputText.setText(text);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: "you're trying to modify a static variable from a non-static method:" That's fine, you cannot access non-static methods from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main extends Application {
//controllers
static HomeController homeController;
static StageController stageController;
//...
}
```

In the initialize methode of your HomeControllers class write :

```
homeController = this;
```

and in the initialize methode of your StageController class write :

```
StageController = this;
```

Comment: This isn't  a great practice. As written it wouldn't work. In the initialize method of HomeController, the this would refer to the home control's this not the main's this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to stem from the fact you're doing your update on the main thread and not on the platform thread. There are two problems here.

- You should always make ui changes on the platform thread.
- You are executing the `UIManager.vbsc.inputText.setText("TEST");` before the launch method.

Try.

```
Platform.runLater( () -> UIManager.vbsc.inputText.setText("TEST") );
```